# How to build a CNN from nifti files?

Tags: conv-neural-network, nifti

I am using COBRE brain MRI dataset containing Nifti files. I can visualize them but could not understand how to use them in deep learning with the correct format. I read Nilearn documentation but they have used only one example of .nii file for 1 subject. The question is how to give 100 .nii files to a CNN?

The second thing is how to determine which slice of the file should be used? Should it be the middle of them? Nifti file consists of 150 slices for each subject's brain.

The third thing is how to provide the model with labels? The dataset doesn't contain any mask. How to give the model specific label for a specific file? Should I create a csv file with path of .nii files and their associated label?

Please explain me or suggest me some resources for the same.

Answer (score 0):

hi i recently got into processing of nii files for one of my projects. i could get a break though to some level (preprocessing) not yet to model level.

for your second question, usually an expert visualise the niis and provide the location(s)  of the roi(region of interest)

I am currently in the process of parsing the nii into  csv format with labels. so the answer to your third question is  , we lable the coordinates (x,y,z,c,t)  as per the  roi locations . (i may need to correct this understanding as i advance on need basis but for now this is the approach to feed the dataset to model i am goin to follow)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).